# Has anyone installed Android ADT (Android Developer Tools) on Linux

Tags: android, android-debug

I downloaded the latest bundled version of the Android Developer Tools (Eclipse with a lot of the android parts already in the package) for windows and Linux.  It is a very nice improvement with a lot of useful tools and features.

One question though, the download for Linux is a zip file and when you unzip it appears that you have to set the permissions on executable files yourself.  Is this true?

In the past, the downloads where tgz files which restored the proper file permissions.

Does anyone know the proper way to install ADT http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download for Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to install the ADT through eclipse. Just add https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ as a repository and install it. Full instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download)

Comment: Hi James, Thanks that works.  Additional note that is not related to your answer, I believe the zip file is misleading for the ADT bundle download for linux.  Thanks again!